# Exploded (unpacked) EAR vs. Packaged EAR file?

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, websphere

In my office we use exploded EAR's (and inside them exploded WAR directories) for our test environments, and then a packaged one for production.  I've yet to find a good explanation of the reason behind this though.  I understand it's easier from a deployment perspective to push out a single file during builds, but it prevents us from doing things like property file changes without doing complete rebuilds (we could skip the compiles, but our environment currently binds the compile and jar processes together).

What are the major advantages / disadvantages between these two configurations?

Answer (score 2):

Even if you deploy a single .ear file, the appserver will unpack it before using it, as well as unpacking the WARs inside that, and sometimes even the JARs also.

So the only benefit of single .ear files is one of deployment convenience.

Answer (score 2):

**Exploded ear** - easy to update and manipulate individual prop files, class files, jsps and make surgical changes.  You do from time to time wonder if the latest production code has all the latest changes because you move each file individually and it would be easy to forget something.  When you deploy, you know exactly what file is being changed with a packaged ear you are updating every single class, jar, jsp in one fell swoop.

**Packaged ear** - simple, easy to deploy, you know with each deployment you are move ALL the latest changes.  prop files are really weird when using an ear, you have to put them on the server(container) and create some kind of absolute path so you know where they are and they are separate from your ear build.

I think I prefer the exploded ear.